# The number of prime ideals lying over a given prime ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra

Put $A = k[x]$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field and $x$ is an indeterminate. Let $B$ be a ring and $f: A \rightarrow B$ be finite integral morphism.

How can one show that the number of prime ideals of $B$ which lie over a given prime ideal of $A$ is finite and bounded?

Comment: Dear Chan: You seem to be a new user. Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I suggest that you read the faq, in particular the part about how to ask questions. I was wondering if you couldn't state your question in a clearer way, and give it a more suggestive title. When I saw your question, it had 2 downvotes. I voted for it. - To the others: Is it really good idea to downvote questions asked by users with almost no reputation points? Aren't there other ways to interact with them? I imagine myself asking a question on a Chinese forum...

Comment: I assumed he was trying to prove that $M(P)$ is bounded as $P$ varies.

Comment: I'm sorry I made some mistakes. Yes, Dylan guessed what I mean. And thank you for your suggestions , dear Pierre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't that $B$ is the ring of polynomials over an algebraically closed field. It suffices that $A \to B$ is a finite extension: if $B$ can be generated by a set of $n$ elements as $A$-module, then for every prime ideal $P$ of $A$ the number of primes of $B$ lying over $P$ is $\leq n$.

For a proof see my answer [Is the number of prime ideals of a zero-dimensional ring stable under base change?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57270/is-the-number-of-prime-ideals-of-a-zero-dimensional-ring-stable-under-base-change/57277#57277)