# Spectrum of finite $k$-algebras

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ be a finite $k$-algebra.

How does one quickly see that $Spec(A)$ is a finite set?

Further, is it true that the cardinality of $Spec(A)$ is equal to $dim_k(A)$?

Comment: For examples where the cardinality of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is strictly less than $\dim_k(A)$, take any finite local $k$-algebra of $k$-vector space dimension greater than $1$, e.g., $A=k[x]/(x^n)$ with $n>1$.

Comment: [Here is an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/701612/3217)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A$ is Artinian for reasons of dimension, and in Artinian rings all primes are maximal and these are finite in number. For proofs, which are quite short, see Section 15 of [Milne's notes](http://jmilne.org/math/xnotes/ca.html).

In this specific case, showing that $A$ has dimension zero should be easier: if $\mathfrak p$ is a prime of $A$ then $A/\mathfrak p$ is a domain finite over $k$, hence a field. Thus $\mathfrak p$ is maximal. I don't see a shortcut for the second step: find maximal ideals such that $\mathfrak m_1 \cap \cdots \cap \mathfrak m_r$ is minimal, and show by contradiction that there are no others.

For a counterexample to your last question, take $A$ to be the ring of dual numbers $k[x]/(x^2)$.

Comment: Another (similar, but slightly different, not totally elementary) argument for why $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is finite: since $A$ is Noetherian, being a finite $k$-algebra, it has finitely many minimal primes, $\mathfrak{p}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{p}_r$, all maximal. Now, $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is the union of its irreducible components, and any prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ lies in one of them, i.e, $\mathfrak{p}\in V(\mathfrak{p}_i)=\{\mathfrak{p}_i\}$ for some $i$, so $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}_i$.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell Oh, that's great. I like that fact because it seems halfway geometric—do you mind if I add that in?

Comment: No, not at all.

Answer (score 6):

In general the cardinality of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is not greater than $\mathrm{dim}_k A$. The key ingredient is Chinese remainder theorem. For a proof you can see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57270/is-the-number-of-prime-ideals-of-a-zero-dimensional-ring-stable-under-base-chang/57277#57277).