# Atiyah & Macdonald's Introduction to Commutative Algebra, Exercise 8.5

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, covering-spaces

The exercise asks the reader to prove that $X$ is a finite covering (i.e., the number of points of $X$ lying over a given point of $L$ is finite and bounded) of $L$, where the affine varieties $X$ and $L$ are defined in the final part of exercise 5.16:

> "...if $k$ is algebraically closed and $X$ is an affine algebraic variety in $k^n$ with coordinate ring $A\neq0$, then there exists a linear subspace $L$ of dimension $r$ in $k^n$ and a linear mapping of $k^n$ to $L$ which maps $X$ onto $L$."

Finally, the mapping $X\rightarrow L$ is given by the linear relation between the $x$'s and $y$'s when we are trying to prove the Noether normalization theorem in the first part of exercise 5.16.

Maybe that's really easy, but I have no idea.

Comment: Please provide the relevant definitions for those who don't own the text

Comment: The result follows immediately from the reasoning given in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/57277/115654) (along with the fact that integral + finite type = finite)

Comment: @zcn thanks a lot.